# Create text element inline with input checkbox list elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to dynamically add a checklist to my page that will look something like this, where [ ] represents a checkbox

```
[ ] something
[ ] something
[ ] something
```

The following code snippet shows what I have so far. As seen, the "somethings" are below the checkboxes, I would like for them to be on the same line.

```js
list = ["something1", "something2", "something3"];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var container = document.getElementById("checklist");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var text = document.createTextNode(list[i]);
        container.appendChild(li).appendChild(input)
        container.appendChild(text)
        input.type = "checkbox"
        li.style.listStyle = "none"
    }
})
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
  }

#directions{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="directions">
        Check off list items!
      </div>
      <div id="checklist"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your javascript:

```
//container.appendChild(text);
li.appendChild(text);
```

```js
list = ["something1", "something2", "something3"];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var container = document.getElementById("checklist");
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var text = document.createTextNode(list[i]);
        container.appendChild(li).appendChild(input);
        li.appendChild(text);
        input.type = "checkbox";
        li.style.listStyle = "none";
    }
})
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
  }

#directions{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="directions">
        Check off list items!
      </div>
      <div id="checklist"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you using div and label elements instead of li elements here.

You might also move `list` from being an array of strings to be an array of objects where each object has an identifier and a label string.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```js
list = ["something1", "something2", "something3"];

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        var container = document.getElementById("checklist");
        var formGroup = document.createElement("div");
        var input = document.createElement("input");
        var label = document.createElement("label");
        
        formGroup.appendChild(input);
        formGroup.appendChild(label);
        container.appendChild(formGroup);

        input.type = "checkbox"
        input.id = list[i];
        label.setAttribute("for", list[i]);
        label.innerText = list[i];
    }
})
```

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
  }

#directions{
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="container">
      <div id="directions">
        Check off list items!
      </div>
      <div id="checklist"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the question is just how to get the checkbox and text on the same line, set your `li`s to `display: inline` or `display: inline-block`. That said, you probably shouldn't be using list items in the first place, especially when the parent isn't a list.